# Java simple chat - Sending message to all clients

Tags: java, sockets, io, chat

I am learning how to program in Java and I decided that i will write simple chat program.

I already wrote Server, Client and ThreadedConnection classes. My goal for now is that a message from one of clients will be shown at other clients.
My current code work in the following way: When one client send a message, others receive it only when they send their own message.
example:
Client1:
hello 
hello
Client2
hi
hello
Client3
Whats up
hi

I think that the issue is in the way I am getting input from server. Probably my program is waiting untill it gets input from user (stdin) and it blocks the execution of further part of program. But honestly I dont know how to do it in other way.

```
if((message=stdin.readLine())!=null)
           out.println(message);
if((message=in.readLine())!=null)
           System.out.println(message);
```

I would be very gratefull for any tips. I was trying to find answer on the internet but usually the programs i found was too hard to understand for me.

Server code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Server {

    private static List<ThreadedConnection> clientList=new ArrayList<>();;

    public synchronized void broadcastMessageToAllClients(String message){

        for(ThreadedConnection tc: clientList)
            tc.sendMessage(message);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try {

            Server server=new Server();
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8189);

            while (true) {

                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                Runnable threadedServer = new ThreadedConnection(socket, server);
                clientList.add((ThreadedConnection)threadedServer);
                Thread thread = new Thread(threadedServer);
                thread.start();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("An error occured.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

ThreadedConnection code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ThreadedConnection implements Runnable {

    private Server server;
    private Socket socket;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private BufferedReader in;

    public ThreadedConnection(Socket socket, Server server) {

        this.socket = socket;
        this.server = server;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            String message;
            while(true){

                if((message=in.readLine())!=null)
                    server.broadcastMessageToAllClients(message);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message){

        out.println(message);
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try (
                Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 8189);
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        ) {

            String message;
            while(true){

                if((message=stdin.readLine())!=null)
                    out.println(message);
                if((message=in.readLine())!=null)
                    System.out.println(message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should have a thread dedicated for reading from the Socket. Also, you might want to look at ServerSocketEx (https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/), which is a framework for handling Sockets

Comment: thanks, i will try to work on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to receive the messages from the console and from the socket at the same time, you should split these functionnalities in to two threads. So the console reader would stay in the main thread (as it is in your actual code), but the socket reader should be in a new thread.

This happens because the function `readLine()` of BufferedReader waits until the next input is received. That means that your socket reader is only called when you type in some text in the console.

Comment: You're welcome ;) (Mark my answer as the solution :p)